# How to infer a method return type from an enum input with Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an AudioProcessor enum:

```
export enum AudioProcessors {
  BiquadFilter = 'BiquadFilter',
  StereoPanner = 'StereoPanner',
  DynamicsCompressor = 'Dynamics​Compressor​',
  None = 'None'
}
```

and a AudioProcessorNode type:

```
export type AudioProcessorNode = BiquadFilterNode | StereoPannerNode | DynamicsCompressorNode;
```

I want to make a class method that takes the enum and returns the correspond Node (from some class properties) but I am not sure how to make Typescript infer the type so that:

```
public getProcessor(audioProcessor: AudioProcessors): AudioProcessorNode {        
   throw new Error(`Method not implemented. ${audioProcessor}`);
}

audioClass.getProcessor(AudioProcessors.BiquadFilter) // returns BiquadFilterNode
```

Looks like what I need is something like [ReturnType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) but I do not know how to put it in my method signature.

Comment: Is the question about the return *type* or the return *value*?

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder is about the return `type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use overloads to make the method return the appropriate type:

```
public getProcessor(audioProcessor: AudioProcessors.BiquadFilter): BiquadFilterNode 
public getProcessor(audioProcessor: AudioProcessors.DynamicsCompressor): DynamicsCompressorNode
public getProcessor(audioProcessor: AudioProcessors.StereoPanner): StereoPannerNode 
public getProcessor(audioProcessor: AudioProcessors): AudioProcessorNode {        
    throw new Error(`Method not implemented. ${audioProcessor}`);
}
```

Or you can use a mapping interface from the enum members to the appropriate return types:

```
interface AudioProcessorNodeMap {
    [AudioProcessors.BiquadFilter] : BiquadFilterNode;
    [AudioProcessors.DynamicsCompressor] : DynamicsCompressorNode;
    [AudioProcessors.StereoPanner] : StereoPannerNode;
    [AudioProcessors.None] : void;
}

class x{

    public getProcessor<T extends AudioProcessors>(audioProcessor: T): AudioProcessorNodeMap[T]
    public getProcessor(audioProcessor: AudioProcessors): AudioProcessorNode {        
        throw new Error(`Method not implemented. ${audioProcessor}`);
    }
}
```

The advantage f this version is if you forget to add a member in the interface you will get an error on the method.

Comment: That was the only answer I could think of as well, but sadly the OP wants it driven by the enum -- e.g., so that adding another entry to the enum is automatically reflected in `getProcessor`. (I should have left my comment asking them that.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah. this the closest that can be done. On the upside with the map version you get an error if you add a member in the enum but not n the map

Comment: Yeah, the map version looks really good. Yes, it's two places rather than one, but...

Comment: Thanks @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I will go with the Map version. The error for keys that aren't in the map is helpful.